# How do you split table cells in Indesign(CC) independent of each row?

Tags: adobe-indesign, tables

Using tables in indesign CC. If you split a row into multiple columns those columns run the entire height of the table - much like in HTML. Can you independently move the cells with the rows, outside of the columns? Below is an example of the general idea. So - I would not be able to move the magenta (second row divider) passed the third row divider (in blue) because according the Indesign these are in separate columns.

[image: Table Example]

Here is a breakdown of what Indesign shows for columns. So the last column divider would not be able to be moved past the dividers of Column 1 or 3. That is what I would like to know. Is it possible, what am I missing?

[image: Example of columns in table]

Comment: Similar to HTML, sometimes a table is not the correct choice.

Comment: Why do you need one table? Making each row a separate one removes this problem.

Comment: Splitting cells still does not create the desired outcome because if you split Column 2, those two new cells still cannot move outside of the width of Column 2. C'mon Adobe, if it can be done in Word, it should certainly be able to be done in InDesign.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create the table w/ more columns than you need, merge columns to create the desired standard appearance, then when you need further flexibility, unmerge cells and join them as needed.

Or, in more recent versions of InDesign, use the command to split cells horizontally or vertically.

Comment: I would up vote your answer if you showed examples and expanded on your answer..   I love visuals, guess it must be the designer inside of me =)

Comment: It’s a simple problem, with a straight-forward solution, which isn’t complex enough to merit further effort.

Comment: Thanks Will. This also elevates distributing cells evenly if built on the right "grid" so to speak!